# 'CachingConnectionFactory(jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory)' cannot be applied to '(com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory)'

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, ibm-mq

In my project, I am using apache camel + ibm mq + spring boot for messaging. I am getting a compile time err which I am not able to resolve.

```
com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactoy = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
// set all the properties to above mqQueueConnectionFactoy such as queue manager etc.
CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(mqQueueConnectionFactoy);
```

Now on the second line I am getting this err:

```
Now on the second line I am getting this err:
'CachingConnectionFactory(jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory)' in 'org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory' cannot be applied to '(com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory)'
```

I have googled a lot but not able to find any such example. Any help would be appreciate. My build.gradle has below dependencies.

```
// Camel
    implementation 'org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-spring-boot-starter:4.0.0-M1'
    implementation('org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-servlet-starter:4.0.0-M1')
    implementation('org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-jaxb-starter:4.0.0-M1')
    implementation("org.apache.camel:camel-jms:4.0.0-M1")
    implementation("org.apache.camel:camel-core:4.0.0-M1")

    // IBM MQ
    implementation("javax.jms:javax.jms-api:2.0.1")
    implementation("com.ibm.mq:com.ibm.mq.allclient:9.1.0.5")
    implementation("com.ibm.ims:udb:15.1.31")
    implementation("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.4.0-b180830.0359")
```

Comment: Does this help: [IBM MQ classes for Jakarta Messaging: an overview](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=messaging-mq-classes-jakarta-overview).  Jakarta started being supported at 9.3. Mark Taylor had a really good blog but it seems to be offline currently.

Comment: Thanks for the comment JoshMc. I also found Mark Taylor's blog offline. And that doc is not helping much. The problem is I am not able to instantiate public CachingConnectionFactory(  jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory targetConnectionFactory )  . It has to take an arg of jakarata.jms.ConnectionFactory which I am not able to find out . I am trying to find any class after new operator : jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory targetConnectionFactor = new .....

Comment: I believe @JoshMc is on the right lines. You cannot mix and match the jakarta and javax namespaces. If you are using jakarta JMS 3.0, then you must use the appropriate matching IBM MQ libraries as well. If you want to use the javax libraries from IBM MQ, then you must not use jakarta libraries (as you appear to be from your error message) elsewhere. Make sure you have a consistent set. It looks like Spring boot 4 uses jakarta, so suggest using the jakarta interfaces instead of the javax interfaces to match.

Comment: The central artifact you have here is the camel-spring-boot-starter:4.0.0-M1 file. You need to find which version of Spring Framework and Spring Boot that is pulling in. If it is using Spring Boot 3.x.x, then that will be the jakarta-based implementation which means you have to have the MQ jakarta.client:9.3 as the MQ JMS prereq. And if you are using Maven Central as the repository, then the MQ artifact will in turn pull in the appropriate jms-api as a dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to replace your `com.ibm.mq.allclient` dependency with `com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client` and replace `javax.jms-api:2.0.1` with `jakarta.jms-api`

Ala

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=umcjm-obtaining-mq-classes-jms-mq-classes-jakarta-messaging-separately

See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mq/com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.jms/jakarta.jms-api for latest versions.